Is it Ok to use a contraction in a UI (such as a tooltip)?
Is it Ok to use a contraction in a UI?
e.g., tooltip for a checkbox:  "If unchecked, items won't be changed"
The userbase for this is native english speakers, above average in computer skill.

I would not, but I tend to be overly cautious about overestimating the English proficiency of my potential audience.

Good point: I updated question to include that user base is native english speaker and computer literat.

It is generally not recommended to use negative statements as they require an additional second to parse, which can become problematic if the user isn't familiar with the concept the UI element is asking about to begin with.
Or to rephrase that to comply with what it says:
It's generally recommended to use positive statements as they are typically simpler.
A similar question has been asked previously here, which may have more input: Checkbox label negating

That said, you're specifically asking about tooltips for checkboxes. So, let's say you have a checkbox called something like
[x] Change All

to which you want to apply the tooltip "If unchecked, items won't be changed". That in principle would be a good place to put the negative; the user just saw a positive statement, still is confused, and reframing the problem in a negative context may be helpful here.
(in this specific example, the "change all" checkbox really is the problem here. It'd probably be more appropriate to have it as an action instead, or to invert the mechanism and lock all fields until they're explicitly unlocked)
